# Vertical links between middle parts of ganttbars in pgfgantt

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I have two ganttbars in a gantt chart using pgfgantt. I want to show that "at this point, the work from here will influence the other part of the project" by making a link that goes from the bottom of a ganttbar to the top of another one at a given time point. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you for your help!!

A toy that one may have is the following:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit chart=.7cm]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2020}{12} 

\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1}

\ganttbar{Project 1}{1}{9}
\ganttbar{Project 2}{4}{12}

\end{ganttchart}
```

I want to show that at Month 5, Project 1 will give lead to information for Project 2. Is there a link that makes this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely I do not understand the question. But perhaps this can be the basis for an answer. Yes, you can link bars.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit chart=.7cm]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2020}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1}\\
\ganttbar{Project 1}{1}{9}\\
\ganttlinkedbar{Project 2}{4}{12}
\ganttlink{elem0}{elem1}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But from your description I am wondering if you are looking for a milestone at month 5 which should be linked.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit chart=.7cm]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2020}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1}\\
\ganttmilestone{}{5}
\ganttbar{Project 1}{1}{9}\\
\ganttmilestone{}{5}
\ganttbar{Project 2}{4}{12}
\ganttlink{elem0}{elem2}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]